# HTML &quot; not converting to ' in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I am creating a django application and was trying to authenticate users on a button click and redirect the users accordingly. I have a button that logs in the user, but I want to redirect the user based on their authentication.

The code is as follows:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" onclick = "location.href='{% url &quot;auth&quot; %}'">Login</button>
```

While running the code I get the error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError 
Could not parse the remainder: '&quot;auth&quot;' from '&quot;auth&quot;'
```

Is this because "*&quot*"; is not working as intended?
Could someone please shed some light on this?

Comment: The `{% url ... %}` part is interpreted by the *template engine*, which happens at the server side, and does not listen to escaped HTML...

Comment: So is there a way I can run the <button> code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `&quot;` and use `auth` as string literal:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" onclick="location.href='{% url 'auth' %}'">Login</button>
```

the template tags and template filters are interpreted by the *render engine* at the server side, not by JavaScript, so this is before the HTML is "interpreted".